# PHP : preg_match_all none xhtml attributes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to improve my code but I do not know how to write the regexp.

I want to get all none xhtml attributes in a tag.

So after the preg match I want to get :

```
array(
  0 => "required",
  1 => "autocomplete"
);
```

`$balise = <input id="myId" class="myClassA myClassB myClassC" required autocomplete/>;`

I actually use this `preg_match_all("/(?<=\s)[\w]+(?=[\s\/>])/i", $balise, $attributs);`

But with the regexp I get :

```
array(
  0 => "myClassB",
  1 => "required",
  3 => "autocomplete"
);
```

I do not want to get `myClassB`...

can anyone help me to write my regex ?

Thx

Comment: Can you post the original data you are using the regex on (`$balise`)?

Comment: parse HTML with parser,not regexp

Comment: Post edited.
simplyParseXML isn't totally understand html, no ?

Comment: Maybe use the [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class to parse your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the negative look-ahead `(?![^=]*?")` to make sure the next " doesn't precede the next =, that way you're getting only words that aren't within a quoted value. Single-quote the string so that the " in the regex won't terminate it.

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=\s)[\w]+(?=[\s\/>])(?![^=]*?")/i', $balise, $attributs);
```